# Copy Table format

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am looking for a solution. There are tables with different formatting on my Power point presentation. I want to choose one of them as a reference to follow for  the other table formats and update all tables from the style accordingly. That means having all tables with the same colors shades with the same background, text colors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The only built in way to do this automatically is if the reference table follows one of PowerPoints "Table Styles". With a table selected, go to the Table Design tab and then select the desired Table Style (see image below).

[image: Select Table > Table Design (Tab) > Table Styles]

If the reference table has custom styling then the only other built in way is to do it manually by copying each style for each custom element and applying it to your other tables one by one.

If you're comfortable editing the backend XML of the PowerPoint file you may want to check this article about creating custom table styles:
http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/08/xml-hacking-table-styles-complete/